# SVN, show version, user and date in name file

Tags: eclipse, svn

How can i do in eclipse ( using svn) to show version, user and date in name file ? when this one is in the repository ?

Answer (score 15):

Go Window->Preferences->Team->SVN-> Label decorations -> Text Decorations, In the format section, check ellipsis for file, check the author.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the team settings:

Window-> Preferences -> Team -> Show all synchronization information in a resource's text label

Eclipse Version: Kepler

Comment: I change it but no modifications, i have only version in name file.

Comment: Try going to Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Label Decorations and make sure SVN is checked. Also, go to Window->Preferences->Team->SVN-> Label decorations and you will see the preview of the labels that should be displayed.

Comment: Sorry it dosn't work, author is dispaleyd file name but not when i synchronize the project. i have only [outgoing addition or  outgoing change]. any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it a new file going into the repository?